# Nginx reverse proxy causes 500 Internal Server error in Jenkins

Tags: authentication, nginx, jenkins

I have a public facing jenkins that I want to secure with nginx/fail2ban.  The nginx reverse proxy works great until I turn on basic auth within nginx.  When I activate the nginx basic auth jenkins gives a 500 Internal Server error.

nginx config:

```
    location /jenkins/ {
            auth_basic "Development";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

            rewrite ^/jenkins(/.*)$ $1 break;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $remote_user;
            proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 $scheme://xxxxx.com.au;
    }
```

nginx access log:

```
XXX.XX.XX.XXX - mark [04/Jun/2017:12:01:35 +1000] "GET /jenkins/login?from=%2Fjenkins%2F HTTP/1.1" 500 595 "https://xxxxx.com.au/jenkins/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Some Noteworthy bits:

- If I comment out the auth_basic entries in the nginx config the proxy
  works fine using jenkins local auth.
- The jenkins log has nothing in it even if I up the debug level
  to 9.
- If I authorise against nginx and then turn off the basic auth
  everything works great. That is the X-Forwarded-User header continues
  to be set (despite that auth is turned off) and forwarded to jenkins
  which correctly authenticates against it's local database.
- I have tried the Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin which does not appear to make 
  any difference.

Comment: Can you move `auth_basic "Development";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;` to server `section` and try rather than `location` section?

Comment: thanks for the tip, however moving the auth to the sever section does not change anything :(

Comment: Okay. Can you check the request headers in browser network console with and without auth?

Comment: thanks for your help,  I can see the additional auth headers in Chrome with auth (i.e. Authorization etc.) turned on.  I tried clearing cookies and this too made no difference.  If I turn off nginx basic auth after having authenticated with nginx the same headers remain and these are getting passed to Jenkins as I can see it is authenticating against it's local db. I really like your thinking, I wonder if there is a way to see the headers between nginx and jenkins.  This does sound like the curlprit.

Comment: I tried the whoAmI page in the Reverse Proxy Auth Plugin however as soon as I turn on nginx basic auth I get the 500 error page.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Reverse+Proxy+Auth+Plugin might help you

Comment: I have tried that plugin but it doesn't make any difference to the 500 error.  That plug in does help with the authentication from nginx.